# Saving one file to two folders

Tags: google-drive-api

In the Google Docs format, I could save one file to two (or more) folders by checking multiple boxes. Now that I've switched to Google Drive, I find that the files that were already in more than one folder stay that way, but I am unable to save a new file to two (or more) files/collections. Am I not doing something correctly or is this an intentional change?

Answer (score 0):

Drag the file to the desired folder and press the Ctrl key before dropping it.
The action changes from Move to Add (mover/Añadir in Spanish).
You get a linked file with joined share permission